# How to get all lists of stations according to the lines they are in?

Tags: list, prolog

I have the following set of facts:

Line names:

```
line(ecLine).
line(wcLine).
line(mLine).
line(gwLine).
line(swLine).
```

Station names and respective list of lines:

```
station(london,       [ecLine, wcLine, mLine, gwLine, swLine]).
station(bristol,      [gwLine, wcLine]).
station(rugby,        [wcLine]).
station(birmingham,   [wcLine]).
station(crewe,        [wcLine]).
station(liverpool,    [wcLine]).
station(manchester,   [wcLine, mLine]).
station(carlisle,     [wcLine]).
station(glasgow,      [wcLine]).
station(edinburgh,    [wcLine]).
station(leicester,    [mLine]).
station(sheffield,    [mLine]).
station(peterborough, [ecLine]).
station(york,         [ecLine]).
station(newcastle,    [ecLine]).
station(edinburgh,    [ecLine]).
station(oxford,       [ecLine]).
```

Stations adjacent to each other:

```
adjacent(london,       bristol).
adjacent(london,       oxford).
adjacent(london,       rugby).
adjacent(london,       leicester).
adjacent(london,       peterborough).
adjacent(bristol,      birmingham).
adjacent(rugby,        birmingham).
adjacent(birmingham,   crewe).
adjacent(rugby,        crewe).
adjacent(crewe,        liverpool).
adjacent(crewe,        manchester).
adjacent(crewe,        carlisle).
adjacent(manchester,   carlisle).
adjacent(carlisle,     glasgow).
adjacent(carlisle,     edinburgh).
adjacent(leicester,    sheffield).
adjacent(sheffield,    manchester).
adjacent(peterborough, york).
adjacent(york,         newcastle).
adjacent(newcastle,    edinburgh).
```

And the following rules:

Rule that makes the adjacent relationships two-way:

```
twoWay(X, Y) :- adjacent(X, Y); adjacent(Y, X).
```

And my rule that returns the list of stations for a given line name:

```
line(Line, StationList) :-
    findall(Station,
        (line(Line),
         station(Station, ListOfLines),
         member(Line, ListOfLines)
        ),
        StationList).
```

This works fine when a line name is given in the query, as follows:

```
?- line(mLine, LineList).
LineList = [london,manchester,leicester,sheffield].
```

But if I don't give a line name to the rule 'line', it will return the following:

```
?- line(Line, StationList).
StationList = [london,peterborough,york,newcastle,edinburgh,oxford,london,bristol|...].
```

It doesn't return all stations because it's too large to be written to the console - at this point I thought it was getting all stations into a single list. However, if I override Prolog's `answer_write_options` as follows:

```
set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(0)]).
```

this is what happens:

```
?- line(Line, StationList).
StationList = [london,peterborough,york,newcastle,edinburgh,oxford,
              london,bristol,rugby,birmingham,crewe,liverpool,
              manchester,carlisle,glasgow,edinburgh,london,manchester,
              leicester,sheffield,london,bristol,london,oxford].
```

It not only gives all stations but some of them are repeated.

In short: Given all the facts above, is it possible to write a rule that returns each line name followed by the list of stations in that line, preferably in the following format (I can tolerate any formatting but this is my preference):

```
Line = ecLine
LineList = [london,peterborough,york,newcastle,edinburgh,oxford]

Line = mLine
LineList = [london,manchester,leicester,sheffield]

Line = ...
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply instantiate `Line` with a `line/1` first:

```
line(Line,StationList) :-
    line(Line), %ground Line with a valid line
    findall(Station,(station(Station,Lines),member(Line,Lines)),StationList).
```

If I query with two uninstantiated variables:

```
?- line(Line,StationList).
Line = ecLine,
StationList = [london, peterborough, york, newcastle, edinburgh, oxford] ;
Line = wcLine,
StationList = [london, bristol, rugby, birmingham, crewe, liverpool, manchester, carlisle, glasgow|...] ;
Line = mLine,
StationList = [london, manchester, leicester, sheffield] ;
Line = gwLine,
StationList = [london, bristol] ;
Line = swLine,
StationList = [london].
```

Or with `Line` fixed:

```
?- line(wcLine,StationList).
StationList = [london, bristol, rugby, birmingham, crewe, liverpool, manchester, carlisle, glasgow|...].
```

Or with `StationList`:

```
?- line(Line,[london]).
Line = swLine.
```

Or finally with both:

```
?- line(wcLine,[london]).
false.

?- line(swLine,[london]).
true.
```

By calling `line(Line)` the result is that from now on `Line` is grounded: so for instance `Line = gwLine`, and then you run the query like:

```
findall(Station,(station(Station,Lines),member(gwLine,Lines)),StationList).
```

Which - like you already found out yourself - finds all the stations that map on a list of `Lines` where `gwLine` is a `member/2` of. These are then put into the `StationList` and can thus be returned.

Comment: Wow, that's a very quick and working answer! Could you explain to me how it works? Thanks!

Comment: @SomeProlog: updated with some explanation, but there is really not much to tell.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I understand it now! Thank you!